# Excel(.xlsx) file download on click of a link in html

Tags: html, excel

None of the options are working out so far for me . I am trying to download an excel file on click of an image link.

What I tried was

```
<div class="export-template-label" style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 5px -8px 0px;">
    <a href="../../Upload/Files/MyGrpMembership.xlsx" target="_self" download>
        <img src="Images/excel.png" alt="logo" style="float:left;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

But when I try to open the downloaded file it shows me error saying

[image]

Comment: Can you post your htaccess? Maybe there is something blocking it?

Comment: If you use absolute reference in the link? So instead of `a href="../../Upload/Files/` use `a href="http://example.com/Upload/Files/`

Comment: @Andreas how to get the htaccess of my project ? Sorry to be ignorant about it .

Comment: @Andreas ... When I try with absolute path like a href="file:///C:/MY TFS/StuartV2/Stuart_V2/App/Upload/Files/MyGrpMembership.xlsx" ... it says file download network error.

Comment: Maybe your server sends the wrong header with the file? Use (eg) Fiddler to see what gets sent.

Comment: Agree with Tim. It sounds as if you got header issues or that the file is in the wrong format. Sometimes it happens with auto generated excel files (php generated or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Does the Excel file exist? Try to open the file directly. I don't think your code is wrong neither relevant.

Comment: File exists . And when I try to open it directly the downloaded file it shows me same error. The funny part is the file I put in the Upload/Files directory , open flawlessly . I don't know why this strange behavior.

Comment: Are you sure it's the right format? xlsx, not xls? try running it from the "Run" window